# Как сделать сортировку строк , состоящих из букв и цифр?

Tags: php

**Например есть строки:**

kollektsiya_komfort_29900

kollektsiya_yuta_23900

kollektsiya_example_18900

kollektsiya_comfort_8900

Строка состоит из названия коллекции, а число это минимальная цена в коллекции.

Мне нужно сделать сортировку этих групп в каталоге по убыванию и по возрастанию. Можно использовать только одно поле для сортировки.

Вопрос, как можно сделать корректную сортировку этих групп/строк

например выбрали desc

- kollektsiya_komfort_29900
- kollektsiya_yuta_23900
- kollektsiya_yuta_23900
- kollektsiya_comfort_8900

например выбрали asc

- kollektsiya_comfort_8900
- kollektsiya_yuta_23900
- kollektsiya_yuta2_23900
- kollektsiya_komfort_29900

Почему не сортирую по числу? Дело в том, что внутри группы/блока выводятся товары.

Т.е мне доступно два поля, 1 нужно задействовать для сортировки групп/блоков , а второе уже для элементов внутри.

Comment: А что Вы сделали? И что не вышло?

Comment: что бы сделать *такую* сортировку я бы наверно *распарсил* исходную строку: отделил группу от цены и делал сортировку по *цене*

Answer (score 0):

я так понял что это у вас на стороне клиента происходит и что вы не можете повлиять на вывод информации, а из за того что у вас входные данные приходят в виде массива строк например

```
$arr=['kollektsiya_komfort_29900','kollektsiya_yuta_23900','kollektsiya_yuta_23900'];
```

лучше конечно получать массив вида

```
$arr[['name'=>'kollektsiya_komfort','value'=>[29900],['name'=>'kollektsiya_yuta','value'=>[23900,23900]]]
```

упрощенный вариант

```
$arr=array( 'kollektsiya_komfort'=>array(29900),'kollektsiya_yuta'=>array(23900,23900) );
```

а второй массив получается такой

```
$arr=array(array('key'=>8900,'val'=>array('kollektsiya_comfort')),array('key'=>23900,'val'=>array('kollektsiya_yuta','kollektsiya_yuta')));
```